# How can I persist objects only during user session

Tags: java, persistence

I am doing a java ee web app (with 3 layers: web,ejb,persistence db). And I want to save some objects but only during session time (not persist them in db). How can I do that? Should I save the objects (pojos) in the managed bean?? like this every user would have its own saved object.

Thanks guys

Comment: What do you mean by "saved", if that doesn't mean "in the DB"? Where else do you want to "save" the objects?

Comment: save during a short period of time while I do some calculations on the ejb.

Comment: Could you please come up with a concrete example? This is much too vague. If the objects are tied to the session, then store them in the session. If they're valid for just a request, then don't store them anywhere, or store them in a request attribute.

Comment: I would just normally save it as an object on the enterprise bean. But I want to save 1 object for every session connected (and the enterprise bean is common for all users). So should I save it in the managed bean as a property???

Comment: by storing them in the session u mean in the session bean( the managed bean)???

Comment: I mean the HTTP session. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/?javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple ways to store some user-specific information in memory during http session.

1. Have session scoped managed bean (annotated [@SessionSoped](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html)). As documentation says:

> The session context is shared between all servlet requests that occur in the same HTTP session. The session context is destroyed when the HTTPSession times out, after all HttpSessionListeners have been called, and at the very end of any request in which invalidate() was called, after all filters and ServletRequestListeners have been called.

This way every user will have his own set of data stored in a session scoped bean for him.

2. Access [HttpSession](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)  directly and store user-specific data there.

   FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
   ...
   session.setAttribute(key, value);
   ...
   session.setAttribute(key);

Comment: And never use stateful EJB in a web application for that purpose since the servlet is its singleton client.